# If then statement with user selected option from JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to create a program in Java that allows a user to set the number of animals he or she wants in her colony, and then ask the user if he or she wishes to give the animals vitamins to reduce sickness. Sickness occurs 25% without a vitamin, and 20% with a vitamin, if an animals become sick, 10% of them die off. The results are listed in a JOptionPane. I have the code below, for some reason when a random number is generated above 25 or 20, the sickness is not set to false, it is still set to true, I found this out by creating a isItSick variable that shows if the vitamin boolean was set to true or false based off of the random number generator.

The math isn't coming out correctly though, I am guessing my problem lies in the if then else statement of the vitamin and JOption Yes and No method, but I am not sure how to fix that.

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Animals {

    private String isithealthy; //Sting stating if the animals took vitamins.
    private String isItSick; //String stating if the animals became sick.
    private int rNumber; //Random number generating for chance of sickness.
    private int requestVitamins;
    private double startingSize; //Starting size of number of animals.
    private double died; //Number of animals died from sickness.
    private double finalSize; //Number of animals left after sickness test.
    private boolean vitamin = false; //If true, decreases chances of getting sick.
    private boolean sickness; //If sick, 10% of starting size of animals die off.

    public void setStartingSize()
    {
        startingSize = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the starting size of your animal colony.",
        "Creating Your Animal Colony", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
    }

    public void setVitamin()
    {
        requestVitamins = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Giving your animals vitamins decreases the chance of your animals from getting sick and dying off. Would you like to give your colony vitamins?",
        "Keeping Your Animals Healthy",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (requestVitamins == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                vitamin = true;
            else
                vitamin = false;
    }

    public void setSick()
    {
        Random number = new Random();        
        rNumber = number.nextInt(100);

        if (vitamin == true && rNumber <= 20)
            sickness = true;

        else if (vitamin == false && rNumber <= 25)
            sickness = true;

        else
            sickness = false;
    }

    public void sickEffect()
    {         
        if (sickness == true)
            finalSize = startingSize*0.10;
            died = startingSize - finalSize;
    }

        public void setHealthyText()
    {
        if (vitamin == true)
            isithealthy = "Yes";
        else if (vitamin == false)
            isithealthy = "No";
    }

    public void setSickText()
    {
        if (sickness == true)
            isItSick = "Yes";
        else
            isItSick = "No";
    }

        public void getFinalDialogOutput()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Starting Size: " + startingSize + "\n Random Number: " + rNumber + "\n Sickness and death: " + isItSick + isithealthy + ", " + died + " died" + "\n  Final size of colony: " + finalSize, "Animal Colony Summary", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
public class AnimalsTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Animals newColony = new Animals();

    newColony.setStartingSize();
    newColony.setVitamin();
    newColony.setSick();
    newColony.sickEffect();
    newColony.setSickText();
    newColony.getFinalDialogOutput();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use == to compare/check and = to assign. Almost all your if conditions are wrong.

Comment: Ok I fixed the = to ==, i edited the code above, but I still am getting "null" for the isithealthy variable even though when I click NO, in the JOptionPane, and make vitamins false, by clicking that, isithealthy should say No, and it sayas null when running

Comment: you need the show the relevant code, you have a bunch of code that isn't relevant to your event handler that you say should be calling this method, well **it isn't** but we can't tell you why!

Answer (score 4):

In some of your if statements, you're using `=` where you should use `==`

```
if (vitamin = true && rNumber <= 20)
```

- `=` is for assignment.  It sets the value of a variable.
- `==` is for comparison.  It checks to see whether 2 variables are equal.

Comment: Ok I fixed the = to ==, i edited the code above, but I still am getting "null" for the isithealthy variable even though when I click NO, in the JOptionPane, and make vitamins false, by clicking that, isithealthy should say No, and it sayas null when running.

Comment: @ZionTodd I don't see where `setHealthyText` is called from

Answer (score 1):

### Since you don't actually show the code that supposedly calls `setHealthyText()`

Here are some tips to make debugging your code easier for everyone.

#### Always use {} even for one liners:

There are too many chances to add a line of logic and forget that it will either always or never execute.

```
public void setHealthyText()
{
    if (vitamin == true)
    {
        isithealthy = "Yes";
    }
    else if (vitamin == false)
    {
        isithealthy = "No";
    }
}
```

the following is acceptable as well for very terse statements

```
public void setHealthyText()
{
    if (vitamin) { isithealthy = "Yes"; }
    else { isithealthy = "No"; }
}
```

#### Don't compare booleans directly to `true/false` it is a tautology and hard to reason about when there are lots of them combined:

`if (someBoolean == true)` should be `if(someBoolean)` or `if(!someBoolean)` to test for `false`

#### Learn to use the proper naming conventions:

variables are `lowerCamelCase` ( `isithealthy` should be `isHealthy` )

methods that return `boolean` should be named `isXXX` or `hasXXX` or some other possessive.

```
isSick()
isHealthy()
hasVitamin()
```

#### Learn to use the ternary statement:

```
public void setHealthyText()
{
    this.isHealthy = vitamin ? "Yes" : "No";
    // variable      boolean    true   false
}
```

#### This a nightmare of confusing code that doesn't have to be:

```
if (vitamin == true && rNumber <= 20)
    sickness = true;

else if (vitamin == false && rNumber <= 25)
    sickness = true;

else
    sickness = false;
```

Corrected:

```
this.sickness = vitamin && rNumber <= 20 || !vitamin && rNumber <= 25;
```

#### Example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    isSick(true, 26);
    isSick(true, 24);
    isSick(false, 24);
    isSick(false, 18);
}

private static void isSick(final boolean vitamin, final int hp)
{
    System.out.println(vitamin && hp <= 20 || !vitamin && hp <= 25 ? "Sick" : "Not Sick");
}
```

Outputs

```
Not Sick
Not Sick
Sick
Sick
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting vitamin equal to true in your conditionals. `=` is the assignment operator. use `==` instead.

Comment: Ok I fixed the = to ==, i edited the code above, but I still am getting "null" for the isithealthy variable even though when I click NO, in the JOptionPane, and make vitamins false, by clicking that, isithealthy should say No, and it sayas null when running